# Angular UI router access parent state resolved data in child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I would want to pass parent states already resolved data to child state onEnter function instead of again making an http call. 
I wanted to do this dynamically instead of passing the parent's resolve because I am generating multiple child states programatically as I will need to use the same child states for multiple parents and I have an angular service which does that.

I recently upgraded angular-uirouter from 0.2 to 1.0.8. 
Previously I used angular-ui-router extras and was able to achieve this using $state.$current.locals.globals., I injected $state to onEnter

```
$stateProvider
  .state('parent',
    resolve:
      parentResolve: (Restangular) -> Restangular.all('route')
  )
  .state('child',
    parent: 'parent'
    url: '/child'
    resolve:
      childResolve: (Restangular) -> Restangular.one('bar')
    onEnter: ($modal) ->
      $modal.open(
        templateUrl: 'templates/modal.html',
        controller: 'ModalCtrl'
        resolve:
          parentResolve: -> parentResolve
          childResolve: -> childResolve
      )
  )
```